ROS 2 colcon build reports error async_web_server_cpp::async_web_server_cpp, the include path is invalid
I encountered the following error while running colcon build in my ROS 2 Galactic workspace:
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt: Imported target "async_web_server_cpp::async_web_server_cpp" includes non-existent path "/include"
I checked that the directory /opt/ros/galactic/include/async_web_server_cpp exists.
I also tried deleting the build directory and recompiling, but the issue persists.
I suspect the issue might be related to an incorrect setting in the CMake configuration files.
How can I resolve this include path error in the async_web_server_cpp package?


Did you source the ROS2 environment?
What's the output of printenv | grep -i ROS?

Yes, I have source the ros environment
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/ros2_ws$ printenv | grep -i ROS ROS_VERSION=2 ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3 PWD=/home/ubuntu/ros2_ws AMENT_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/galactic PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gazebo-11/plugins:/opt/ros/galactic/opt/yaml_cpp_vendor/lib:/opt/ros/galactic/opt/rviz_ogre_vendor/lib:/opt/ros/galactic/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu:/opt/ros/galactic/lib ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0 PATH=/opt/ros/galactic/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin ROS_DISTRO=galactic
